# CLI command with Click package Python

Tags: python, pandas, click, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using click library in order to call function from one folder and read file and after that to write file.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import click

def count_unique_port(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:    
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.groupby(['A1', 'A2'], as_index=False).size()
    return port

@click.command(help="Pandas count")
@click.option("-i", "--input", "infile", type=click.File(), default=sys.stdin, help="Input file name")
@click.option("-o", "--output", "outfile", type=click.File("w"), default=sys.stdout, help="Output file name")

def main(infile, outfile):
    df = pd.read_csv(infile)
    temp = count_unique_port(df)
    print(temp)
    temp.to_excel(outfile, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()
```

The problem that I stumble upon is when I call python script `python path1/read_data.py ./path/data/f1.csv ./path/data/f2.xlsx`

It does not write the pandas dataframe to the folder path. What I am doing wrong? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you define [Options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/options/#options), not [Arguments](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/arguments/). Run it as:

```
python path1/read_data.py -i ./path/data/f1.csv -o ./path/data/f2.xlsx
```

And you need to specify the output file for "writing":

```
@click.option("-o", "--output", "outfile", type=click.File("w"), default=sys.stdout, help="Output file name")
```

note the `"w"` as a parameter of `click.File("w")`

Comment: It does not work again.

Comment: Please provide more details on what "does not work" means. Do you get an error? Unexpected result? If so, include error/result in your question.

Comment: I run the command in the way that you mentioned. It does not save again the dataframe.

Comment: Does it show any errors? Or just silently exits without printing anything?

Comment: I found a mistake here is the error. Error: Invalid value for '-o' / '--output': './apth/data/f2.xlsx': No such file or directory

Comment: Run command now I see KeyError: 'Fund'

Comment: Please edit your question to post the whole traceback

Comment: I found the mistake I have issue with the pandas dataframe. Thanks for help.